# Can work on a system increase entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, work

If you add Heat on a constant volume container, disorder will increase, so Entropy will increase.
But what if I do some work on a piston-cylinder? I'll give more kinetic energy to particles, so they gain more disorder, but they also occupy a smaller volume, thus particles would be more organized (less entropy). 
Is this valid? Can work create entropy? I ask this because $$ dS=\frac{dq}{T}$$
By this equation it seems that entropy only depends on Heat, not in work.

Comment: $dU = TdS-pdV$... so?

Answer (score 5):

Reversible work transfers no entropy and generates no entropy; when you adiabatically and reversibly compress a gas, for example, the entropy increase from the higher temperature exactly offsets the entropy decrease from the smaller volume, as you intuited. However, irreversible work generates entropy because it involves a gradient in some field (e.g., pressure, force, electric field, etc.). When this gradient drives a transfer of energy, entropy is created.

Comment: thanks so much for you answer. It was helpful. So the change of entropy on the system after a reversible and adiabatic process would be zero. So the entropy production is zero.  What about a diabatic reversible process? The change of entropy wouldn't be zero, right? So the entropy production wouldn't be zero as well, right? And if it was a cycle of diabatic reversible processes? The change and production of entropy would be zero?

Comment: Yes, heat transfer consists of entropy transfer. Yes, reversible processes don't generate entropy (reversible heating only transfers entropy).

Comment: so the entropy production during a diabatic reversible process is zero.  Reversible processes, either it be a cycle or just 1 process, don't generate entropy, it just can change or not. Right? 
I got another question, if you would like to help me. 
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/330960/why-do-we-consider-heat-transfer-from-to-reservoirs-a-reversible-process